# Substitute first occurrence of keyword if occurrence between two other keywords

Tags: regex, sed

Assume a string with three different keywords (abbreviated as "kw").

```
> echo "foo kw1 bar kw2 baz kw3"
```

I would like to replace "kw2" with some other string, say "qux". What am I missing in the following *sed* command?

```
> echo "foo kw1 bar kw2 baz kw3" | sed 's/\(kw1\)kw2\(.*kw3\)/\1qux\2/'
# Current output: foo kw1 bar kw2 baz kw3
# Desired output: foo kw1 bar qux baz kw3
```

*EDIT 1*:
Actually, I would like to have only the **first** occurrence of kw2 being replaced if there are multiple occurrences. How would the suggested *sed* command need to be modified?

```
> echo "foo kw1 bar kw2 baz kw3 kw2 baz kw3" | sed ...
# Desired output: foo kw1 bar qux baz kw3 kw2 baz kw3
```

*EDIT 2*:
For clarity: If there are multiple occurrences of kw2, the occurrence to be replaced is the first one that is preceded by kw1 somewhere in the string (i.e., kw1 not necessarily adjacent to kw2) and followed by kw3 (i.e., kw2 not necessarily adjacent to kw3 either).

```
> echo "foo kw2 bar kw1 bar kw2 baz kw3" | sed ...
# Desired output: foo kw2 bar kw1 bar qux baz kw3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask can't be done with `sed` and multiple chars delimiters (as `kw2`) cause there is no support to lazy modifier or lookahead.

**PERL**

In `perl` you can simply use the lazy modifier `*?`:

```
echo "foo kw1 bar kw2 baz kw3 foo kw2 bar kw3" | perl -pe 's/(\bkw1\b.*?)\bkw2\b(.*?\bkw3\b)/\1qux\2/'
# output -> 'foo kw1 bar qux baz kw3 foo kw2 bar kw3'
```

**SED**

The problem in `sed` can be solved only if the delimiters was single chars.

Given then a single char that is not contained in the input string (actually one char per delimiter of a greedy section `.*<delimiter>`)  you can use this approach:

```
echo "foo kw1 bar kw2 baz kw3 foo kw2 bar kw3" | sed 's/\bkw2\b/~/g' | sed 's/\bkw3\b/#/g' | sed -E 's/(\bkw1\b[^~]*)~([^#]*#)/\1qux\2/' | sed 's/~/kw2/g' | sed 's/#/kw3/g'
# output -> 'foo kw1 bar qux baz kw3 foo kw2 bar kw3'
```

*NOTE*: i've used extended version of regex `sed -E` in the main expression to avoid escaping round brackets

**Algorithm**

- `s/\bkw2\b/~/g`: replace every `kw2` (not substring) into `~` (supposing there is no other `~` in the input string)
- `s/\bkw3\b/#/g`: replace every `kw3` (not substring) into `#` (supposing there is no other `#` in the input string)
- `s/(kw1[^~]*)~([^#]*#)/\1qux\2/`: using the negated char class `[^~]*` and `[^#]*` select only till the first kw1 (first tilde) and the first kw3 (first hash).
- `s/~/kw2/g`: restore kw2
- `s/#/kw3/g`: restore kw3

Comment: How would you make the code by user _falsetru_ "greedy" (i.e., only the **first** occurrence of kw2 being replaced)?

Comment: Actually you need to make it *lazy* (it has to stop at the first keyword ``kw2``, a greed one go till the last occurrence) but this can't be done using the @falsetru regex because ``sed`` doesn't have support to lazy modifier ``*\?`` or negative lookahead ``\(?!kw2\)``). Use my second example: ``echo "fookw2 kw1 bar kw2 baz kw3" | sed 's/\bkw2\b/qux/'``

Comment: @MichaelGruenstaeudl: if you want to keep your line (why?) switch to perl to obtain the lazy modifier: ``echo "foo kw1 bar kw2 baz kw3 kw2 baz kw3" | perl -pe 's/(kw1.*?)kw2(.*kw3)/\1qux\2/'``

Comment: Your second example doesn't help me, because kw2 may occur prior to kw1 (e.g. `echo "foo kw2 bar kw1 bar kw2 baz kw3"`). I am looking for code that replaces the first instance of kw2 that is **enclosed** by kw1 and kw3.

Comment: @MichaelGruenstaeudl: this is a different question, now i know what you really want to do

Comment: I added another example in the question above to  illustrate my point. Any idea on _sed_ code that can fullfill both conditions (i.e., first occurrence and enclosed by kw1 and kw3)?

Comment: @MichaelGruenstaeudl: i've updated the answer to solve your request using ``sed`` (assuming you identify some missing symbols in the input string), if you can switch to ``perl`` to accomplish this kind of tasks to simplify your life (perl has a more powerful regex support).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `\(kw1\)` to `\(kw1.*\)` so that character between `kw1` and `kw2` to be matched:

```
$ echo "foo kw1 bar kw2 baz kw3" | sed 's/\(kw1.*\)kw2\(.*kw3\)/\1qux\2/'
foo kw1 bar qux baz kw3
```

Comment: Actually, how can I make the above substitution "greedy" (i.e., only the **first** occurrence of kw2 being replaced)? Consider, for example, the following input: `echo "foo kw1 bar kw2 baz kw3 kw2 baz kw3"`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/kw1/&\n/;T;:a;s/\n$//;t;s/\nbar/qux/;t;s/\n(.)/\1\n/;ta' file
```

This inserts a newline after `kw1` and then bumps along a character at a time until the target string is found and replaced.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed [here](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/262856-substitute-first-occurrence-keyword-if-occurrence-between-two-other-keywords.html), the following *perl* command provides the correct substitution:

```
perl -ple 's/(kw1.*?)kw2(.*?kw3)/$1qux$2/'
```

There may be alternatives, but this command seems the most straightforward I have encountered.

Examples:

```
> echo "foo kw2 bar kw1 bar kw2 baz kw3" | perl -ple 's/(kw1.*?)kw2(.*?kw3)/$1qux$2/'
# foo kw2 bar kw1 bar qux baz kw3

> echo "foo kw1 bar kw2 baz kw3 kw2 baz kw3" | perl -ple 's/(kw1.*?)kw2(.*?kw3)/$1qux$2/'
# foo kw1 bar qux baz kw3 kw2 baz kw3
```

Comment: This is exactly the same regex i've used without the ``\b``. They are there for a reason: using your code with this example input string ``"fookw1bar kw2 bar kw1 bar kw2 baz kw3"`` you obtain  ``fookw1bar qux bar kw1 bar kw2 baz kw3`` (replace the wrong ``kw2``).